# AVD Camera Preview Size too small

Tags: android, camera, emulation, android-virtual-device, preview

I'm using Android Developer Tools (Build v22.0.5-757759) and running an Android Virtual Device (AVD) for testing my camera app.

This is the code:

```
Camera camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```

The method call:

```
parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()
```

only returns the 320x240 size.

Is there any way to configure other sizes in the AVD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a webcam, see http://www.ecole.ensicaen.fr/~reynaud/android/webcam_in_android_emulator.html

The resolution depends on hardware.